# Why these xamarin pages are not being showed in my app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a xamarin application that tests login data at App.cs(OnStart() method) and based on its success, show a content page or the login page. It was working fine before but today I see only a white screen, by analyzing with breakpoints, I could see that MainPage is altered to the correct page. I have tried to delete obj and bin directories but no success.

```
protected override async void OnStart()
        {
            if (App.CheckInternet())
            {
                if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("userid") && App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("usertoken"))
                {
                    var dados = await Logar();

                    if (dados.status == "ok") // it has the expected result
                    {
                        if (dados.fAccess)
                            Application.Current.MainPage = new CompletaCadastroProf(); // it doesn't work!
                        else
                            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage(); // it works properly!
                    }
                    else
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new Login(); // it doesn't work!
                }
                else
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new Login(); // it works properly!
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage = new SemInternet(); // it works properly!
            }
        }
```

The page is correct assigned to MainPage but it doesn't appears.

I know the correct way to navigate is by using Navigation.PushAsync() but I don't want allow back to previous page.

What is strange is the fact of MainPage = new Login(); works as expected in a block but not in other block. Are you guys seeing something wrong?

Comment: It would be good if you could share the `CompletaCadastroProf` code with us. My guess would be that there's some XAML issue(s) that is causing an exception but you might be ignoring exception (setting in VS) and therefore it's not being thrown. Check your output window for any exception(s) information.

Comment: Can you please show us the codes om your loginPage and CompletaCadastroProf Page? Does you load anything in the constructor?

Comment: The error is not in login page and/or CompletaCadastroProf because if I comment all the lines out from OnStart() and put only MainPage = Login() or MainPage = CompletaCadstroProf() it works properly. The problem occurs only inside the if/else statement.

Comment: @MikolajKieres there is no exceptions!

Comment: I've just realized that if I set any page to MainPage before if (App.CheckInternet()) line, everything works fine.

Comment: Is the `CheckInternet` method an `async` operation? If so, you should `await` it

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint there to see if the code has been hit? Can you share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: @MikolajKieres the method was not async, I have transformed it into async and tried to await for it but same issue.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes, the code is being hit properly. I will try to update the question with a minimal example asap.

Comment: OK, I will check once you updated.